# How is wallet at official client encrypted? What encryption it use?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, multibit, encryption

How is wallet at official client encrypted? What encryption it use?

What encryption does Bitcoin-qt use and what encryption is used at Multibit?
And how strong that encryption is compared to other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both bitcoind and bitcoinj use AES-256 encryption for the private keys in their wallets (this does not mean that the wallet formats are compatible though).

Bitcoin-Qt is just a GUI on top of bitcoind and Multibit is using bitcoinj internally, so the same should apply to them.

References:

- [comment in the bitcoind source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/crypter.h)
- [bitcoinj documentation](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/wiki/WorkingWithTheWallet#Encrypting_the_private_keys)

Comment: what strength of AES?

Comment: If by strength you mean key length it's 256 bit in both cases.

Comment: ok, please add it to the post and add information how long does it take to crack it by supercomputers and how can quantum cryptography break that stuff.

Comment: I don't know and I think this would be off-topic for this site. But I'm pretty sure you'll find the answer on [crypto.se].